# In OpenTBS demo an image is replaced, where in code is this done?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have problem to understand how to manage the image replace. So I look into the demo project (demo_ms_word.php) but I can't find the PHP code where definition and the actual image replace is done.

Template

```
[b.number;ope=changepic;from=pic_[val].png;tagpos=inside;adjust;unique]
```

PHP (Only showing the main part and not include and output)

```
// Initialize the TBS instance
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong; // new instance of TBS
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN); // load the OpenTBS plugin

// ------------------------------
// Prepare some data for the demo
// ------------------------------

// Retrieve the user name to display
$yourname = (isset($_POST['yourname'])) ? $_POST['yourname'] : '';
$yourname = trim(''.$yourname);
if ($yourname=='') $yourname = "(no name)";

// A recordset for merging tables
$data = array();
$data[] = array('rank'=> 'A', 'firstname'=>'Sandra' , 'name'=>'Hill'      , 'number'=>'1523d', 'score'=>200, 'email_1'=>'sh@tbs.com',  'email_2'=>'sandra@tbs.com',  'email_3'=>'s.hill@tbs.com');
$data[] = array('rank'=> 'A', 'firstname'=>'Roger'  , 'name'=>'Smith'     , 'number'=>'1234f', 'score'=>800, 'email_1'=>'rs@tbs.com',  'email_2'=>'robert@tbs.com',  'email_3'=>'r.smith@tbs.com' );
$data[] = array('rank'=> 'B', 'firstname'=>'William', 'name'=>'Mac Dowell', 'number'=>'5491y', 'score'=>130, 'email_1'=>'wmc@tbs.com', 'email_2'=>'william@tbs.com', 'email_3'=>'w.m.dowell@tbs.com' );

// Other single data items
$x_num = 3152.456;
$x_pc = 0.2567;
$x_dt = mktime(13,0,0,2,15,2010);
$x_bt = true;
$x_bf = false;
$x_delete = 1;

// -----------------
// Load the template
// -----------------

$template = 'demo_ms_word.docx';
$TBS->LoadTemplate($template, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8); // Also merge some [onload] automatic fields (depends of the type of document).

// ----------------------
// Debug mode of the demo
// ----------------------
if (isset($_POST['debug']) && ($_POST['debug']=='current')) $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_DEBUG_XML_CURRENT, true); // Display the intented XML of the current sub-file, and exit.
if (isset($_POST['debug']) && ($_POST['debug']=='info'))    $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_DEBUG_INFO, true); // Display information about the document, and exit.
if (isset($_POST['debug']) && ($_POST['debug']=='show'))    $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_DEBUG_XML_SHOW); // Tells TBS to display information when the document is merged. No exit.

// --------------------------------------------
// Merging and other operations on the template
// --------------------------------------------

// Merge data in the body of the document
$TBS->MergeBlock('a,b', $data);

// Merge data in colmuns
$data = array(
 array('date' => '2013-10-13', 'thin' => 156, 'heavy' => 128, 'total' => 284),
 array('date' => '2013-10-14', 'thin' => 233, 'heavy' =>  25, 'total' => 284),
 array('date' => '2013-10-15', 'thin' => 110, 'heavy' => 412, 'total' => 130),
 array('date' => '2013-10-16', 'thin' => 258, 'heavy' => 522, 'total' => 258),
);
$TBS->MergeBlock('c', $data);


// Change chart series
$ChartNameOrNum = 'a nice chart'; // Title of the shape that embeds the chart
$SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 2';
$NewValues = array( array('Category A','Category B','Category C','Category D'), array(3, 1.1, 4.0, 3.3) );
$NewLegend = "Updated series 2";
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

// Delete comments
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_COMMENTS);
```

Could someone point out the definition and merge where the image is replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template, the field is named `[b.number;...]` so it is merged with a block (or a field) named 'b', and the sub-item `number`.

We see it is corresponding in the PHP snippet to  `$TBS->MergeBlock('a,b', $data);`. This code is merging both block 'a' and 'b' with the recordset $data.

So `[b.number;...]` is merged with the column `number` of the recordset $data. Yo can see that this column has values such as '1523d', '1234f', ...

Parameter `ope=changepic` makes the value of the field to be the path of the picture to replace. But the final path is arranged with parameter `from=pic_[val].png` wich makes the value of the field '1523d' to be corresponding to the path 'pic_1523d.png'.
That is how the picture is changed.

Parameter 'from' is not needed  with `ope=changepic` if the value of the field is directly the path of the image to replace.

Comment: It makes sense! I got it as long to the merge and data-array, but no fields "looked" as a picture field and I got lost... With your explanation, it's obvious what's happened.

Thank you for a good explanation!